Type '{....}' is not assignable to type 'TableHeaderProps'
Fairly new to TypeScript and need to implement a toggle action between data-table and tree-view component using IBM Carbon library in React.js
Getting the following error from this line -
<TableHeader {...getHeaderProps({ header })} key={header.key}>                        {header.header}</TableHeader>

Error:
'Type '{ children: ReactNode; key: string; isSortable: boolean | undefined; isSortHeader: boolean; onClick: (e: MouseEvent) => void; sortDirection: DataTableSortState; }' is not assignable to type 'TableHeaderProps'.
  Types of property 'onClick' are incompatible.
    Type '(e: MouseEvent) => void' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>'.
      Types of parameters 'e' and 'event' are incompatible.
        Type 'MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>' is missing the following properties from type 'MouseEvent': layerX, layerY, offsetX, offsetY, and 16 more.'

Need some pointers on why we get the error and how to resolve/ avoid it further. Appreciate all the help I can get.
import React from 'react';
import TreeView from '@carbon/react/lib/components/TreeView/TreeView';
import TreeNode from '@carbon/react/lib/components/TreeView/TreeNode';
import { Document } from '@carbon/icons-react';
import { DataTable, Table, TableBody, TableCell, TableContainer, TableHead, TableHeader, TableRow } from '@carbon/react';
import Button from '@carbon/react/lib/components/Button/Button';

const headers = [
  { key: 'name', header: 'Name' },
  { key: 'path', header: 'Path' },
  { key: 'description', header: 'Description' },
];

const rows = [
  { id: 'node-1', name: 'Node 1', path: 'Root', description: 'Activity for Sales scenario' },
  { id: 'node-1-1', name: 'Node 1.1', path: 'Root/Node 1', description: 'Activity for Sales scenario' },
  { id: 'node-2', name: 'Node 2', path: 'Root', description: 'Activity for Sales scenario' },
  { id: 'node-3', name: 'Node 3', path: 'Root', description: 'Activity for Sales scenario' },
  { id: 'node-3-1', name: 'Node 3.1', path: 'Root/Node 3', description: 'Activity for Sales scenario' },
  { id: 'node-3-2', name: 'Node 3.2', path: 'Root/Node 3', description: 'Activity for Sales scenario' },
  { id: 'node-3-3', name: 'Node 3.3', path: 'Root/Node 3', description: 'Activity for Sales scenario' },
  { id: 'node-4', name: 'Node 4', path: 'Root', description: 'Activity for Sales scenario' },
  { id: 'node-4-1', name: 'Node 4.1', path: 'Root/Node 4', description: 'Activity for Sales scenario' },
  { id: 'node-4-2', name: 'Node 4.2', path: 'Root/Node 4', description: 'Activity for Sales scenario' },
  { id: 'node-4-2-1', name: 'Node 4.2.1', path: 'Root/Node 4/Node 4.2', description: 'Activity for Sales scenario' },
  { id: 'node-4-3', name: 'Node 4.3', path: 'Root/Node 4', description: 'Activity for Sales scenario' },
];

interface TreeNodeComponentProps {
  selectedNodes: string[];
  handleSelect: (event: { id: string }) => void;
  toggleNode3Expansion: () => void;
  isNode3Expanded: boolean;
}

const TreeNodeComponent: React.FC<TreeNodeComponentProps> = ({
  selectedNodes,
  handleSelect,
  toggleNode3Expansion,
  isNode3Expanded,
}) => {
  const [showDataTable, setShowDataTable] = React.useState<boolean>(false);

  const toggleView = () => {
    setShowDataTable(!showDataTable);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button kind="secondary" onClick={toggleView}>
        {showDataTable ? 'Show Tree View' : 'Show Data Table'}
      </Button>
      {showDataTable ? (
        <DataTable rows={rows.filter(row => selectedNodes.includes(row.id))} headers={headers}>
          {({ rows, headers, getHeaderProps, getRowProps }) => (
            <TableContainer>
              <Table>
                <TableHead>
                  <TableRow>
                    {headers.map(header => (
                      <TableHeader {...getHeaderProps({ header })} key={header.key} >
                        {header.header}
                      </TableHeader>
                    ))}
                  </TableRow>
                </TableHead>
                <TableBody>
                  {rows.map(row => (
                    <TableRow {...getRowProps({ row })} key={row.id}>
                      {row.cells.map(cell => (
                        <TableCell key={cell.id}>{cell.value}</TableCell>
                      ))}
                    </TableRow>
                  ))}
                </TableBody>
              </Table>
            </TableContainer>
          )}
        </DataTable>
      ) : (
        <TreeView selected={selectedNodes} onSelect={handleSelect}>
          <TreeNode id="node-1" label={<><Document /> Node 1</>} isExpanded>
            <TreeNode id="node-1-1" label="Node 1.1" />
          </TreeNode>
          <TreeNode id="node-2" label={<><Document /> Node 2</>} />
          <TreeNode id="node-3" label={<><Document /> Node 3</>} isExpanded={isNode3Expanded}>
            <TreeNode id="node-3-1" label="Node 3.1" />
            <TreeNode id="node-3-2" label="Node 3.2" />
            <TreeNode id="node-3-3" label="Node 3.3" disabled />
          </TreeNode>
          <TreeNode id="node-4" label={<><Document /> Node 4</>} isExpanded>
            <TreeNode id="node-4-1" label="Node 4.1" disabled />
            <TreeNode id="node-4-2" label="Node 4.2">
              <TreeNode id="node-4-2-1" label="Node 4.2.1" />
            </TreeNode>
            <TreeNode id="node-4-3" label="Node 4.3" disabled />
          </TreeNode>
        </TreeView>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default TreeNodeComponent;


Shouldn't it be ...getHeaderProps(header)?

It seems to be a known bug with Carbon' React library, basically the issue is that some components define the onClick handler as MouseEvent whereas others use React.MouseEvent (which is generic), in this case getHeaderProps is returning an object defined as MouseEvent but TableHeader is expecting a React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>.
Since you're directly passing the return value of getHeaderProps which is handled by the library itself, this would be a good case for typing it as any since the typing is anyways managed by the library:
<TableRow>
  {headers.map((header) => (
    <TableHeader
      {...(getHeaderProps({ header }) as any)}
      key={header.key}
    >
      {header.header}
    </TableHeader>
  ))}
</TableRow>

